# Yii Framework get user data

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can I get currently online user data with all the parameters from the database? Right now I get it's ID by using this:

```
echo Yii::$app->user->getId();
```

Can I reach other data somehow or do I have to create a function which gets all the information by the user ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to all the identity values in this way

this for username

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->username
```

check for your User  models for others attributes

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

(and your User  model of course)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the model of the currently logged in user with:

```
$user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
```

This will return either null (if the user is not logged in) or an instance of the `identityClass` you defined for the `user` component in your config. Ex:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

So you can use it like any other model class and access it's attributes and/or methods. Just make sure you configure correctly the `user` component and the `identityClass` exists and can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

current user is:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity
```

it can be null, so check it before accessing fields

Comment: Object of class backend\models\User could not be converted to string